# Low frequency and high frequency noise of ecg

Tags: signal-detection, ecg

Is baseline wander in ecg is low frequecny noise in ecg and power line interference is high frequency noise in ecg? Is both the artifacts present in EMG signal?

Comment: Why do you ask? Can you give some more information? Based on my guess at what a heartbeat looks like I would say yesto the first question, but if they are present depends on the signal.

Answer (score 1):

The frequency content of baseline wander is usually in the range below 0.5 Hz, while power line noise is somewhere around 50/60 Hz accompanied by some harmonics.